# Batch file Rename file with variable appended to filename?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, batch-rename

I want to rename with appended and also remove the extension of all *.jpg

```
ex. gr1.jpg
gr2.jpg
fx1.jpg
```

to

```
gr1_32dpi
gr2_32dpi
fx1_32dpi
```

This is my command

```
for %a in (*.jpg) do ren "%~a" "%~_32dpi%~xa"
ren *.jpg .*
```

but this `*for %a in (*.jpg) do ren "%~a" "%~na version 1%~xa"*` command not working

When saving as .bat then run getting error like this

> [The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
>   Substitution is invalid: %~na version 1%~xa"
>   For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
>   extensio2.bat was unexpected at this time.]

But it works directly run in cmd

Comment: Use  double percent, when using a for variable, the code in bat/cmd file. Like: %%a

Comment: Nice nw working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
for %a in (*.jpg) do ren "%a" "%~na_32dpi"
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

check out the "Variable with modifier" section